# Palindrome in C using scanf and no string library functions

Tags: c

the assignment is to get an input string, and using no string library functions to be able to handle the string. this code at the moment doesn't even print out the string i get in. when I remove the functions from main it magically starts to print. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 32

int isQuit(char str[]);
void isPalindrome(char str[]);


int main (){
    int cont = 0;
   char str[SIZE];
   fflush(stdin);
   printf("please enter a word:\n");
   scanf("%s\n", str);
   printf("%s\n", str);

  while(cont == 0)
  {
    scanf("%s\n", str);
   printf("%s\n", str);
     cont =  isQuit(str);
    isPalindrome(str);
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use standard capitalization.

Comment: `return 0;` in your `while` loop in `main` means the loop will execute at most once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely are suffering from line buffering in your terminal.  Until you write a newline character, any characters written are not displayed.

Try adding a newline when displaying your input:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

The same goes for any other `printf` calls you do that you want to ensure are displayed.

By the way, your null-termination test is incorrect.  The escape character is `\`, not `/`.  Change your loop to:

```
while (str[h] != '\0')
```

Or simply:

```
while (str[h])
```

Comment: thanks for the catch, but it's still hanging up. several IDE's online and off don't get past input.

Comment: Your original question never mentioned or asked about hanging.  Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?  Did you add newlines to _all_ your printf calls as I suggested?  Did you fix the null-termination test I pointed out?  Is the code you're using otherwise the same code you posted (i.e. with the return inside the loop that will prevent a hang)?  Are you certain that all strings input will be 31 characters long or shorter?  Do you realize your `isPalindrome` function is quite broken?

Comment: thank gentlmen i got it up and running, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code here:

```
while(isQuit(str) == 0)
{ 
    isPalindrome(str);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Since you have the return keyword in your loop body (unconditionally), the loop will execute at most one time.

Also, neither `isQuit` nor `isPalindrome` take input from the user.  This means that even if you were to fix the loop by removing the `return` statement, it *still* wouldn't be right; you'd have an infinite loop of `isQuit` and `isPalindrome` being passed the same `str` that the user got asked for on line 15.

What you have to do is change your `while` loop to continually poll the user for input and act upon it, in addition to the issues pointed out in @paddy's answer.